# Specify __str__() Representation in Django Admin list_display

Tags: django, django-models

Not sure if this is a good way to do things (this is more of a technical question), but what if I have a Django model with `__str__` function that combines several fields:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.field0} {self.field1} {self.field2}'
```

In the admin, I might have the `list_display` like so:

```
list_display = ['field0', 'field1']
```

How do I specify this to use the object representation returned by the `__str__` function?

```
list_display = [<__str__() representation>, 'field0', 'field1']
```

By default, if you don't specify `list_display` in the admin, [it'll give me what I want](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). Can't I have both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add *callables* to the [**`list_display`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), so you can add **`str`**:

```
def model_str(obj):
    return str(model_str)
model_str.short_description = 'Object'


class MyModelAdminAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    list_display = [model_str, 'field0', 'field1']
```

this is thus a reference to the builtin [**`str(…)`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Comment: I thought about this, but it seems odd and somewhat redundant since I already defined the `__str__` representation and Django uses it by default. I was hoping for something simpler that I missed. Thanks for providing this, though, it's very concise.

Comment: It only seems so. But how can you get the string representation of *that instance* at declaration time? By the way it's trivial to create a base model that defines a property that returns self.__str__(). Actually - looks like you can pass `'__str__'` as it will look for model methods as the 4th option...

Comment: Good point. Still relatively new to Python and Django so these things sometimes escape me. I actually already went down a similar path for another `list_display` option so as it turns out, I've got a base class that has another callable already. I was thinking Django had something builtin I was missing but clearly not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done simply by just adding `list_display = ['__str__',]` in the ModelAdmin class. Basically `__str__` is a python method which gives the representation of a python class and list display allows callables.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: This doesn't allow sorting on alphabetically in the admin section, unfortunately